# Deconvolution of data convolved by a Gaussian response

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, fft

I have a set of experimental data `s(t)` which consists of a vector (with 81 points as a function of time `t`).

From the physics, this is the result of the convolution of the system response `e(t)` with a probe `p(t)`, which is a Gaussian (actually a laser pulse). In terms of vector, its FWHM covers approximately 15 points in time.

I want to deconvolve this data in Matlab using the convolution theorem: `FT{e(t)*p(t)}=FT{e(t)}xFT{p(t)}` (where `*` is the convolution, `x` the product and `FT` the Fourier transform).

The procedure itself is no problem, if I suppose a Dirac function as my probe, I recover exactly the initial signal (which makes sense, measuring a system with a Dirac gives its impulse response)

However, the Gaussian case as a probe, as far as I understood turns out to be a critical one. When I divide the signal in the Fourier space by the FT of the probe, the wings of the Gaussian highly amplifies those frequencies and I completely loose my initial signal instead of having a deconvolved one.

From your experience, which method could be used here (like Hamming windows or any windowing technique, or...) ? This looks rather pretty simple but I did not find any easy way to follow in signal processing and this is not my field.

Comment: This is probably more suitable on Signal Processing StackExchange: http://dsp.stackexchange.com . Hi @PaulR !

Comment: @rayryeng: Hi Ray - yes, you're right - the OP needs to understands the basics of deconvolution before trying to code this in MATLAB, so it's more DSP theory than programming.

Comment: This opens up a huge can of worm.  "the side lobes of the Gaussian highly amplifies those frequencies and I completely loose [sic] my initial signal instead of having a deconvolved one" is not quite true.  First of all, Gaussian has no side lobe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_lobe).  Second, you don't lose your signal by amplifying those frequencies.  The problem is that your signal is attenuated at high freq from the convolution.  After that, typically noise gets added.  Inverting the convolution by amplifying, noise also gets amplified.  How to deal with this is the subject of books...

Comment: Thx. I found a way to avoid the noise amplification by zeroing the spectrum of the data for each point in the spectrum of the broadening operator (the filter) below a certain threshold (i.e. that would amplify the signal after division). Moreover, to avoid oscillatory effects at the boundary of the time-window after the whole procedure, I padded it with same values than that at the boundary. I got physical results  (i.e. when supposing a filter with narrow spectrum, I get sharper data after deconvolution). Im not expert in signal processing, that's why I am asking feedback for such a problem.

Comment: Related Question - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/use-matlab-to-restore-the-signal-from-a-given-degraded-signal-using-tikhonov-reg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do Deconvolution process by assuming the Filter Model is Gaussian Blur.
Few notes for doing Deconvolution:

1. Since your data is real (Not synthetic) data it includes some kind of Noise.
   Hence it is better to use the Wiener Filter (Even with the assumption of low variance noise). Otherwise, the "Deconvolution Filter" will increase the noise significantly (As it is an High Pass basically).
2. When doing the division in the Fourier Domain zero pad the signals to the correct size or better yet create the Gaussian Filter in the time domain with the same number of samples as the signal.
3. Boundaries will create artifact, Windowing might be useful.
4. There are many more sophisticated methods for Deconvolution by defining a more sophisticated model on the signal and the noise. If you have more prior data about them, you should look for this kind of framework.
5. You can always set a threshold on the amplification level for certain frequencies, do that if needed.
6. Use as much samples as you can.

I hope this will assist you.

Comment: Thanks!
It helps indeed a lot to have this global overview. I got good results with my previous comments but I will go now to Wiener filters for "automatically" adjusting the level of amplification in the Fourier space, as suggested. It seems to present the advantage to use as few assumption as possible (which seems to be a disadvantage of the point 5). Do you know BTW a way to determine, at least approximately, the spectral density of the noise in a given set of data?

Comment: If you can find "Flat" area, you can approximate the STD there. Yet it is only approximation.

Answer (score 1):

You have noise in your experimental data, do you? The problem is ill-posed then (non-uniquely solvable) and you need regularization.

If the noise is Gaussian the keywords are [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) or [Wiener filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter).

Basically, add a positive regularization factor that acts as a lowpass filter. In your notation the estimation of the true curve o(t) then becomes:

o(t) = FT^-1(FT(e)*conj(FT(p))/(abs(FT(p))^2+l))

with a suitable l>0.